# moving files with error handling in Java SE 6

Tags: java, file, file-io, move

I want to move some file to other place, using Java SE 1.6

So, I have two files:

```
File srcFile, dstFile;
```

When I want to move file srcFile to the place of dstFile:

```
boolean result = srcFile.renameTo(dstFile);
```

But there some errors can occur, and result will be false. In this case I want to ask user if he wants to repeat this operation. Which is the best way to do this? I would use a goto statement here, but Java doesn't have it.

Currently, I am doing it in this way:

```
boolean retry = false;
do {
    if (!srcFile.renameTo(dstFile)) {
        // TODO: Error during file replacement
        Object[] retryOptions = { "Yes", "Retry" };
        replaceFileOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "There was a error durring moving file" + srcFile.getPath() + ". Skip this file?", "Warning", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                    retryOptions, retryOptions[0]);
        if (replaceFileOption == 2) 
            retry = true;
    }
} while (retry);
```

Is there another way, which will not be using while() cycles?

Comment: Smells like premature optimization if you're worried about what I would imagine would amount to a few cycles at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your goal was to avoid an extra var, do it this way

```
while (!srcFile.renameTo(dstFile)) {
       Object[] retryOptions = { "Yes", "Retry" };
       if (2 != JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "There was a error durring moving file" + srcFile.getPath() + ". Skip this file?", "Warning", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                retryOptions, retryOptions[0])) break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place your code into a method and recursivly call the method again in the case of retry.

However, in the end you want to loop some how, and therefor you have to loop in any way.

You could just avoid a certain keyword